# Autorun процесс в фоновом режиме

Tags: linux

Всем добрый день!

Есть программа, консольная, которая будет работать в фоновом режиме и запускаться вместе с ОС (Linux). Интересует материал как это организовать. Работать именно с api Linux раньше не пробовал.

Comment: /opt/bin/myprog & - не?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов интересует какой либо печатный материал где описывается данная проблема, чтобы не "просто сделать и забыть", а еще и разобраться в данном вопросе.

Comment: в чем вопрос? создать инит скрипт запуска вашей тулзы?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Программа, которая работает в фоновом режиме назывется [демоном](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)). Соответственно, нужно гуглить на тему "демонизации". Вот хорошая статья на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/129207/).  Основная задача демонизации - отцепиться от консоли.

Конечно, можно запустить и с & в конце, но вот когда консоль будет закрыта, процесс также закроется.

И последий этап - это сделать демон запускаемым при старте системы. Тут все зависит от системы инициализации, но в последнее время очень сильно распрострянился systemd (даже пробрался в дебиан). Без systemd уже почти нет дистрибутивов (разве что генту и слака, а также старые не обновленные сервера).

Поэтому опишем его. Опять же, на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/centosadmin/blog/255845/) есть статья. Если кратко - нужно будет сделать текстовый документ, в котором описать, как запускать приложение и что делать в случае его падения (как перезапустить). Также указать зависимости (к примеру, если демону нужна сеть, то можно сказать, что бы он запускался только тогда, когда поднялась сеть).

P.S. А можно ли по простому? можно, есть [nohup](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) - стандартная утилита. Она как раз делает две вещи - отвязывает от терминала и игнорирует hup сигнал (этот сигнал посылается процессу при закрытии родительского терминала. Если процесс его не обработает, то будет закрыт).

Answer (score 2):

открываешь крон.

```
crontab -e
```

вставляешь команду.

```
@reboot /opt/bin/myprog
```

Теперь при перезагрузке автоматически запустится эта программа.

Answer (score 0):

`/opt/bin/myprog &` - запуск программы в фоновом режиме.

man bash гласит:

> Если команда завершается управляющим оператором &, интерпретатор
>   выполняет команду в фоновом режиме в порожденном интерпретаторе.